# cqlsh ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh

I am unable to use cqlsh on mac.
 below is my system info and error log I am getting.

```
  os        : mac  
  cassandra : apache-cassandra-3.9   
  python    :2.7.16  
  jave .    : 1.8
```

```
cqlsh 
$ cqlsh
```

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
```

Comment: this could be related: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3964

Answer (score 8):

Reinstalling python 2.7 helped resolve this for me

> brew reinstall python@2

Answer (score 1):

I think it has a dependency on the OpenSSL libraries for MD5, SHA1, etc.  Try installing OpenSSL once:

```
brew install openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was coming due to python(might be some dependency issue) installed via brew.
I have done below steps

1) brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@2
2) install python from https://www.python.org/getit/

below 4 steps suggested by mihgen on below github reference link
1) brew install openssl
2) brew link openssl --force
3) brew uninstall python
4) brew install python --with-brewed-openssl

reference : https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/22816